# Why do the mother German shepherd eats her newborn puppies?

Tags: dogs, pregnancy, german-shepherd

I have a German shepherd pair. Female gave birth to 5 puppies very first time. But she ate 3 of her puppies and killed the other 2. Why did she eat her puppies? What should i do next time she gives birth?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would get her Vet checked as it may be a medical problem, research calcium supplement for dogs during birth.

I would also consider not breeding her again if she has it in her to kill/eat the pups. It can be a hereditary trait, if you are going to do it again seriously do some research on calcium supplementing a whelping bitch, get her health tested and make sure she has all her nutritional and behavioural needs

Comment: she was in proper care during her gestation. I took her to vet after 2 weeks. If i talk about her behavior she is so friendly and jolly but we were really surprised and shocked with her behavior toward her puppies. Some people said its natural in German Shepherds  that they eats their own puppies

Comment: It’s not normally in any dog, I’m a veterinary Nurse and have experience with working with dog breeders. A lot of dogs will react badly if they aren’t given calcium during whelping. Was she from a reputable registered breeder? If so the breeder should be mentoring you. If not maybe contact some reputable registered breeders and ask them to mentor you in breeding GSD. It’s good to hear she’s been to a vet but there’s a lot to breeding that a general practise vet may not necessarily know. Reproductive veterinary care is a speciality. I hope I’ve helped :) let me know if you have more questions